# Toast.makeText is not displaying what iam sending

Tags: android, toast

hi , I am writing a code in eclipse that works as follows:

- click on the button to take me to second activity
- in second activity , iam adding 2 numbers and send the sum of them to first activity.
- in the first activity it should popup a message containing the sum of the two numbers .
  Every thing is okk , except displaying the message , its not appearing.

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
  public void onClick(View view){
      startActivityForResult(new Intent("co.example.SECONDACTIVITY"),request_code);
  }
  public void onActivityResult(int result,int requestcode,Intent data)
  {
      if(requestcode == request_code)
      {
          if(result == RESULT_OK)
          {
              Toast.makeText(this,data.getData().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
  }

  }
  ```

**second activity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);
}
public void onClick(View view){
    EditText b1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText b2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    int x =Integer.parseInt(b1.getText().toString())+ Integer.parseInt(b2.getText().toString());
    String s = Integer.toString(x);
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.setData(Uri.parse(s));
    setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
    finish();

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secondactivity, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You messed up with parameters. Please check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)

Comment: thank you :) , did mean that this method(onactivityresult) came with a predefined parameters so i have to put them same name with same order ??

Comment: name does not matter but order do. Your order is quite different :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

I think you messed up with parameters. You have wrongly comparing parameters.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestcode == request_code)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,data.getData().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Make sure your result code is same** and If it is coming  with same Request Code na you just Print like this and try to print your Data..In your Toast...**And increase your Toast timing**

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
  {
     if(requestcode == request_code)
     {
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
       {
          Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this,data.getData().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
     }
  }
```